# Why is my applescript not working?

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to make an applescript that will click in the same spot over and over again buy i can't get it to work.

```
tell application "Safari"
activate
end tell
repeat
tell application "System Events"
    click at {1, 1}
end tell
delay 1
end repeat
```

Comment: How do you know it's not working?  There's not a lot to go on here.  Also within the System Event tell you should put the application.  tell application "System Events" 
tell application "Safari" 
activate 
click at {745, 75} 
end tell 
end tell 
Also are you expecting global or local coordinates?

Comment: I would suggest updating your question to explain what you are trying to accomplish (which is why you are getting the negative votes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to tell System Events in which application the click should be executed, like the following example (this should theoretically open your bookmarks, if you have a maximised Safari window):

```
tell application "System Events" to tell application process "Safari"
    click at {5, 75}
end tell
```

On a side note, you should think about a better title for your question next time, this is too general.